# Packing additional arrays within `tf.data.Dataset` that should be ignore by the keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using a `tf.data.Dataset` to feed input samples to a Keras model. The signature of the dataset (after batching) is:

```py
element_spec=({'inp_A': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 900, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), 
               'inp_B': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 900, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), 
              TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))
```

Essentially, X are two inputs, named `inp_A` and `inp_B`, each a Tensor of shape (900, 1), while y is a single label of shape (1,)

Each sample `(X, y)` comes from a data sample with multiple of these (900, 1) segments. A data sample, for instance, may have `inp_A` and `inp_B` with shape (n, 900, 1), so it contributes to n `(X, y)` samples to the model.

Therefore, it is useful for me to store an 'index', for each sample `(X, y)`, of which data sample it originated from. One idea I had was to 'pack' this index in the `tf.data.Dataset` creation, such that it would have a signature:

```py
element_spec=({'inp_A': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 900, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), 
               'inp_B': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 900, 1), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), 
               'index': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)}, 
              TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))
```

This is convenient for a few reasons, for instance, I would not need to keep track of another array of indexes, and every `tf.data.Dataset` operations (filtering, batching, shuffling, ...) would reflect in the indexing array as well.

I know that, when creating the model, I can just ignore the `index` key within the `X` of the `tf.data.Dataset`, and it will work just fine, the only thing being the warning:

```py
UserWarning: Input dict contained keys ['index'] which did not match any model input. They will be ignored by the model.
  inputs = self._flatten_to_reference_inputs(inputs)
```

However, I've been wondering: is there a more 'proper' way to pack this auxiliary structure within the `tf.data.Dataset` without raising any warning when model fitting?